# How to remove index.php from each folder and subfolder?

Tags: scripts

My server got hacked and in each folder and subdirectory index.php was placed. I removed index.php in main folders and was able restore my website. However hacker placed index.php in each subdirectory. How can delete them? Can a script be used to recursively to delete index.php? Or is it better to apply backup?

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016844/bash-recursively-remove-files) link. The question relates to deleting .DS_Store files, but it can be easily adapted for your situation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use your backups, if you have them. If not, you can use `find` to delete the files:

```
find /path/to/site/folder -type f -iname 'index.php' -delete
```

This deletes regular files (`-type f`, so not directories) named `index.php` (ignoring case).